# How do I line up 3 divs on the same row?

Tags: css, html

Can someone please help me with this problem as i have been dealing with it for a long time now....

I am trying to get 3 divs on the same line next to each other one of the divs looks like this:

```
<div>  
  <h2 align="center">San Andreas: Multiplayer</h2>  
  <div align="center">
    <font size="+1">  
      <em class="heading_description">15 pence per slot</em>  
    </font>  
    <img src="http://fhers.com/images/game_servers/sa-mp.jpg" class="alignleft noTopMargin" style="width: 188px; ">  
    <a href="gfh" class="order-small">  
      <span>order</span></a>  
  </div>
```

and the other two are the same divs please help me get all three divs on the same line one on the right one on the mid and one on the left

Comment: 1) Welcome to SO.   2) Formatting your html (with newlines, indenting, etc.) would make that much easier to read.  3) You need to be a little clearer on what you need. Should these fill the width of the page or use their default sizes?

Comment: I edited it for formatting. Be gentle on a newbie, they did paste in the html and applied code format which is pretty good for a score 1 newbie imho

Comment: @Michael Durrant agreed not bad for first post.

Comment: May I suggest that where html is the issue, you use jsfiddle (in addition to showing it here), to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: fejsall we are trying to help but we don't write the code as you suggest.  The one part you need to do is type or copy and paste it yourself.  You still need to do a little bit of the work :)  The model you suggest about writing the code 'for you' is called paid work as time=money

Comment: Please do not post answers unless they _answer_ the question, use the comment facility instead :)

Comment: For this task do not use divs. Use tables, quick, predictable, lot less code and most important... it works.

Answer (score 151):

I'm surprised that nobody gave CSS table layout as a solution:

```css
.Row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /*Optional*/
    table-layout: fixed; /*Optional*/
    border-spacing: 10px; /*Optional*/
}
.Column {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red; /*Optional*/
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
    <div class="Column">C1</div>
    <div class="Column">C2</div>
    <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>
```

Works in IE8+

Check out a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/LDnfQ/)

Comment: Maybe because someone thought that "tables are bad". This is true for non-table data in the _markup_. But we're talking styling here. And there is nothing wrong with styling an element to behave like a table. I upvoted this. :-)

Comment: Tables are only way of achieving layout.

Comment: .Row > div
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}

Comment: @GeorgeNorberg yes, you can do that.

Comment: Note you might need to add % width to the `table-cell` divs to get them to display exactly how you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565213/how-to-distribute-multiple-divs-sections-within-same-row

Comment: Can fixed height of Column and display scroll ?

Comment: Because it is not a "best-practice" :D

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov well.. a lot changed since 2013. nowadays - I wouldn't recommend this. just use flex or grid.

Answer (score 42):

See my code

```css
.float-left {
    float:left;
    width:300px; // or 33% for equal width independent of parent width
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2 align="center">San Andreas: Multiplayer</h2>
    <div align="center" class="float-left">CONTENT OF COLUMN ONE GOES HERE</div>
    <div align="center" class="float-left">CONTENT OF COLUMN TWO GOES HERE</div>
    <div align="center" class="float-left">CONTENT OF COLUMN THREE GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ye i used this...

`#leftcolumn {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
}
#midcolumn {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 300px;
}
#rightcolumn {
 float: right;
 width: 300px;
}`

but everything just messes upp with the site... and the mid also doesnt work...

Comment: Put `float: left; width: 300px;` inside #leftcolumn, #midcolumn and #rightcolumn

Comment: wont it just set everything to go left??

Comment: Everything go to left, but first div have 300px of width, so, the second start 300px from left, and the third 600px from left, so the first is on the left, second on the center and third on the right.

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure how I ended up on this post but since most of the answers are using floats, absolute positioning, and other options which aren't optimal now a days, I figured I'd give a new answer that's more up to date on it's standards (float isn't really kosher anymore).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.column {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    <div class="column">Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2<br>Column 2<br></div>
    <div class="column">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

here are two samples: http://jsfiddle.net/H5q5h/1/

one uses `float:left` and a wrapper with `overflow:hidden`. the wrapper ensures the sibling of the wrapper starts below the wrapper.

the 2nd one uses the more recent `display:inline-block` and wrapper can be disregarded. but this is not generally supported by older browsers so tread lightly on this one. also, any white space between the items will cause an unnecessary "margin-like" white space on the left and right of the item divs.

Comment: ok still nothing sadly... but i will paste the html code and the css if you could put it in that would be great .. THANKYou starts from line 44 http://pastebin.com/rW5bfjsv and the css... http://pastebin.com/9yrRTYCh please could you juss put it in and re upload to pastebin.com that would really help me as i have been trying this soooo much and no result ThankYou

Comment: whoa! that's a lot of code. in my example, you just replace my "item divs" with your divs, and retain the class names. don't forget the wrapper. and by the way, jsfiddle is the way to go here in SO.

Comment: +1 for inline-block. floats are not to be used for layout, it should be used to float images within text and such. display: inline-block is the way to go.

Comment: inline block has issues on older browsers. at last i found the link where it states it all: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/ which is why i prefer the overflow+float left method.

Comment: ok still nothing sadly, it will help sooooo much if you just added it in to my code as i tryed dooin it and it didnt work... but i will paste the html code and the css if you could put it in that would be great .. THANKYou starts from line 44 http://pastebin.com/rW5bfjsv and the css... http://pastebin.com/9yrRTYCh please could you juss put it in and re upload to pastebin.com that would really help me as i have been trying this soooo much and no result ThankYou

Answer (score 11):

Old topic but maybe someone will like it.

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/74ShU/

```
<div class="mainDIV">
    <div class="leftDIV"></div>
    <div class="middleDIV"></div>
    <div class="rightDIV"></div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.mainDIV{
    position:relative;
    background:yellow;
    width:100%;
    min-width:315px;
}
.leftDIV{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
.middleDIV{
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.rightDIV{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    background:green;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**2019 answer**:

Using CSS grid:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know how many elements will be in the grid, you can replace the `template` rules with `grid-auto-flow: column`

Comment: hey thanks for the up to date CSS answer, would you mind adding an example with `grid-auto-flow: column` that was provided in the comment? I can't figure out the correct way of using that when number of columns is unknown. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just add float left property on all the divs you want to make appear in a row other than last one. here is example

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left;">A</div>
  <div style="float: left;">B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier and gives purpose to the never used unordered/ordered list tags.

In your CSS add:

```
    li{float: left;}  //Sets float left property globally for all li tags.
```

Then add in your HTML:

```
    <ul>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>        
    </ul>
```

Now watch it all line up perfectly!  No more arguing over tables vs divs!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't try to use bootstrap's solutions. They are perfect if you don't want to meddle with tables and floats.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> <!--- This line is just linking the bootstrap thingie in the file. The real thing starts below -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No meddling with complex CSS, and the best thing is that you can edit the width of the columns by changing the number. You can find more examples at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the foundation rapid prototyping framework they handled this quite nicely, basically they allow you to use HTML like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="four columns">
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the simplest HTML/CSS grid system that I've come across, it's based on 12 column grid.

Basically the columns are given a % width and left margin relative to the parent row. They columns have float set to left, position set to relative, and display set to block.

The row has several properties set on it that care core of an issue that normally causes the containing div to collapse to height of 0 preventing the following divs from getting 'pushed' down as they should.

You can find examples of using the foundation grid system here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php

If you don't want to use the entire framework the following CSS should do the trick with the example code I provided:

```
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.four.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

If you really specifically want a left center and right columns then use code like this:

CSS:

```
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="center">center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the divisions in 'td' tag. That's it done.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pankajparashar/EAzj6/1/ Check the link with all the divisions on the same line....exactly what u have asked for..let me know if u were expecting something else.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
<div>
  <h2 align="center">
  San Andreas: Multiplayer
</h2>
    <div align="center">
<font size="+1"><em class="heading_description">15 pence per
slot</em></font> <img src=
"http://fhers.com/images/game_servers/sa-mp.jpg" class=
"alignleft noTopMargin" style="width: 188px;" /> <a href="gfh"
class="order-small"><span>order</span></a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Also helpful as well.