# CSS, center menu

Tags: css, header, navigation, center

I've got 3 divs inside one div. - Header
I want to center the menu, and the other divs have to be placed left and right.

[Click here to see link.](http://pilarcoaching.dk/hiltonkoksal/buy/)

It's build up like this:

```
<header>
<div id="header-left"></div><div id="menu"></div><div id="header-right"></div>
</header>
```

Just can't seem to get it to work.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I line up 3 divs on the same row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690841/how-do-i-line-up-3-divs-on-the-same-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made couple amendments:

```
#menu {
    /*margin-left: 80px; removed */ 
}

#menu {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    /*float: left; removed */
    margin: 27px auto 0; /* changed */
    width: 33%;
    z-index: 122;
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: need to keep the float:left, otherwise it will go down on next line.
but almost got it now, it's alright and almost in the middle. he he
Just added 33% width and changed some stuff.

Thx

Comment: @Sabine Quardon Welcome :) Accept the answer, if it was helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to resize the elements as the window shrinks, the best solution would be using flexbox. I'm linking an article for you: [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/)

Answer (score -1):

You could easily do that with making the `heading` act like a table:

```
<header>
    <div>left</div>
    <div>center</div>
    <div>right</div>
<header>
```

```
header {
    background: green;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
header div {
    display: table-cell;
}
header div:nth-child(1) {
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
}
header div:nth-child(2) {
    background: lightblue;
}
header div:nth-child(3) {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/qpAkK/)**

Both outer divs have a fix width, and the one in the middle will the rest of the space.
Hopes this helps you.

[EDIT]
In order to center the menu add `text-align: center` to the second div.

Comment: I really don't mind downvotes, but I would like an explanation why... Please provide.