# how to make three divs line up horizontally

Tags: html, css, image, text

trying to make three divs line up.  heres what I'm working with

```
<div id="final_space">
    <div id="sub_cat_1">About</div>
    <div id="sub_cat_2">Contact</div>
    <div id="sub_cat_3">F.A.Q.</div>
</div>
```

I've tried making the css for each of the sub_cat's be float: left, center, and right respectively, but for some reason they wont line up

Comment: pls show css code too.

Comment: use [flexbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg)

Comment: You can refer this stackoverflow thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690841/how-do-i-line-up-3-divs-on-the-same-row

Comment: possible duplicate of [horizontally aligning divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277311/horizontally-aligning-divs)

Comment: Although `float` is a traditional method for inlining elements, it can be tricky to manage. It can make a mess of the container as well as elements which follow. See answer below for a more current solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `float:left` or `display:inline-block` to achieve this.
Try this snippet

```css
.sub-cat {
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="final_space">
    <div class="sub-cat" id="sub_cat_1">About</div>
    <div class="sub-cat" id="sub_cat_2">Contact</div>
    <div class="sub-cat" id="sub_cat_3">F.A.Q.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods, but the most manageable way to get just a horizontal layout is to display the inner `div` elements as `table-cell`:

```
div#final_space>div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Note that the selector above is more usable than trying to class the inner `div` elements.

To spread them out evenly takes a little more work. You need to change the display of the container `div`.

```
div#final_space {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This works in all current browsers, *even* IE8.

```css
div#final_space>div {
 display: table-cell;
 /* For visibility only: */
 text-align: center;
 border: thin solid #999;
}
div#final_space {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="final_space">
    <div id="sub_cat_1">About</div>
    <div id="sub_cat_2">Contact</div>
    <div id="sub_cat_3">F.A.Q.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the like its exactly how you want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/d4kVk/179/

```
 div { height: 45px; }
div.side {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 72px;
    float: left;
}
div#range {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 216px;
    float: left;
}
span {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 3px auto;
    /* background-color: gold; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

float centre doesn't exist. You should you classes here rather than divs. You can do it a number of ways. The first way:

```
.sub_cat {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.final_space:before,
.final_space:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.final_space:after {
  clear: both;
}
.final_space {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

Alternatively you could do it like this with inline block.

```
.sub_cat {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: -4px;
   }
```

Flexbox is another way but not cross browser yet.

Answer (score -1):

best is to use bootstrap grid system

```
 <div id="final_space" class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4" id="sub_cat_1">About</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="sub_cat_2">Contact</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" id="sub_cat_3">F.A.Q.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution of forcing him to use bootstrap is "wrong". He did not tag bootstrap. A pure HTML/CSS solution is needed.

Comment: I think that’s a typo: _worst_ is to use bootstrap …