# How To Distribute Multiple Divs / Sections Within Same Row

Tags: css

I'm trying to create spacing between three different `<div>s` within a row. I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690841/how-do-i-line-up-3-divs-on-the-same-row) but for some reason I'm getting bad results:

[image] Also, I'm not trying to space the three sections out evenly like he wants to in that article. This is exactly what I'm going for:

[image]

So I should have three separate sections - one for "Responsive Website by Gateway Web Design", one for the social media links, and one for the scroll to the top arrow. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
</body>
<footer>
<div class="footer-row">

<div class="responsive-website-by">
    <p>Responsive Website by <a href="http://www.gatewaywebdesign.co.uk/" target="blank">
    Gateway Web Design</a>
    </p>
</div>

<div id="social-links">
    <a href="http://youtube.com" target="blank">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="http://instagram.com" target="blank">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com" target="blank">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </a>        
    <a href="http://facebook.com" target="blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div id="scroll-to-top">
    <button id="scroll-to-top-icon" onclick="scrollToTop(1000);">^</button>
</div>

</div>
</footer>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* FOOTER */

footer {
background-color: #000000;
height: 55px;
}

.footer-row {
display: table;
width: 100%; /*Optional*/
table-layout: fixed; /*Optional*/
border-spacing: 10px; /*Optional*/
}

#social-links {
padding-right: 40px;
display: table-cell;
}

#social-links a {
color: white;
float: right;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 20px;
margin-top: 15px;
}

#social-links a:hover {
color: #966948;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.responsive-website-by {
color: #BCBEC0;
float: left;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-top: 3px;
display: table-cell;
}

.responsive-website-by a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-website-by a:hover{
color: #966948;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#scroll-to-top {
float:right;
display: table-cell;
}

#scroll-to-top-icon {
background-color: #966948;
border: none;
font-size: 35px;
height: 30px;
width: 34px;
padding-bottom: 31px;
}
```

Besides not being able to space them out the way that I want horizontally, I don't understand why they're also being pushed down outside of the footer. I tried commenting out the margins / paddings for those selectors but the problem still remained:

[image]

Please help! Thank you.

**EDIT**:

[image]You can see in this screenshot that the `responsive-website-by` div is automatically being pushed down within the footer, not to mention how the other divs are being pushed down - why?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @iuliu.net sure one moment....also please see the edit above.

Comment: Js Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/jn32sxjr/1/. It looked like fiddle wasn't supporting the font-awesome icons so I substituted them with their respective initials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use percentages for the divs. You can still use the idea of a `table` for the parent div, and `table-cells` for the divs that it contains (as it was suggested in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690841/how-do-i-line-up-3-divs-on-the-same-row)), but in order to space them out the way that you want, you need to give them percentages. So you'll have this in your HTML:

```
<div class="footer-row">

    <div class="responsive-website-by">
        <p>Responsive Website by <a href="http://gatewaywebdesign.com" target="blank">
        Gateway Web Design</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="social-links">
        <a href="http://youtube.com" target="blank">
            <i class="fa fa-youtube" style="font-size: 24px"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com" target="blank">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="font-size:24px"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com" target="blank">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:24px"></i>
        </a>        
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="blank">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size:24px"></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="scroll-to-top">
        <img id="back-to-top-icon" src= "http://websiteroot/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/back-to-top-icon-01.jpg" onclick="scrollToTop(1000);"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this in your CSS:

```
.footer-row {
display: table;
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed; /*Optional*/
border-spacing: 10px; /*Optional*/
background-color: #000000;
}

.responsive-website-by {
color: #BCBEC0;
display: table-cell;
font-family: PT Sans Narrow;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
clear: both;
width: 70%
}

#social-links {
display: table-cell;
color: #ffffff;
width: 25%;
}

#scroll-to-top {
display: table-cell;
width: 5%;
}
```

In order to get the spacing that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would try taking away the "float" attribute on .responsive-website-by, that can mess with attributes like height, and padding, etc... From what I see, it covers the whole screen, so it shouldn't have to float. I don't know if that will directly solve your problem, but from what I've seen, that probably has something to do with it.

Comment: Getting rid of the `float: left` on `.responsive-website-by` causes the social media links to drop below the `.responsive-website-by` div: https://jsfiddle.net/jn32sxjr/2/