# Arranging 2 Div's Parallel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

**Problem :**

- https://ibb.co/dkof1U
- https://ibb.co/d5Vw89 (FIXED)
- the second div always ends up inside the first div.

**Code :**

`<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: 50%; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"> .... </div>
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: 50%; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"> .... </div>`

**Tried Case :**

- Tried floating the first div and the second div but, the second div always ends up inside the first div.

**Todo :**

- Want to arrange div's together side by side.

UPDATED FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/genackwp/

- to view what I see, view the (FIXED) image instead.

THANKS

Comment: What two divs are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/genackwp/ my code i've added comments. <!-- LEFT DIV -->, <!-- Should be outside left div -->. thanks

Comment: See, if it helps, tried only doing the first-div float : https://jsfiddle.net/no5u2a87/

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] in the question itself. Is there anything else wrapping the two divs? Please try to reproduce the issue with as little code as possible then share that code with us. It is hard to associate what little code you have with the image of the problem. You should also describe your problem, then provide the image to further illustrate the issue.

Comment: I considered all your answers useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Similar Helpful Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690841/how-do-i-line-up-3-divs-on-the-same-row)

Just give your first div a class specifier to identify, and give it a `float:left` or just provide it in the inline style of that div.

Providing `float:left` to only first-div

```css
div:first-child {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div style=" overflow-y:scroll;width: calc(50% - 10px); height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"> .... </div>
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: calc(50% - 10px);padding-left:10px; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"> .... </div>
```

Inline-style : `float: left`

```html
<div style="float: left; overflow-y:scroll;width: calc(50% - 10px); height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"> .... </div>
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: calc(50% - 10px);padding-left:10px; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"> .... </div>
```

Comment: this one works, but it affects all the contents of the div. how can I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, using this please update your jsFiddle with your inside code, so we can see, According to the asked question we can only adjust the divs in parrallel for you.
Please upadte jsfFiddel, so we can see and answer.

Comment: I'll update my jsfiddle. Also, I'll update the image link provided. It seems like this isn't the case. I think it is a bootstrap problem. Whenever a content on the left side div, the right side div ends up inside the first div. But when I put the content on the right div, it works without any problem.

Comment: I upvoted it, it said I don't have enough reputation but it is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: 50%; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9; float:left; position:fixed;"> .... </div>
<div style="overflow-y:scroll; width: 50%; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9; float:left; position:fixed;"> .... </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/xpvt214o/605285/

Add `position:fixed;` to your code.

try this..It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;position:fixed; width: 50%; height: 100vh; background-color: #ACDBC9;"><div>
```

try add "position:fixed;", see can work or not